# How to configure hybrid graphics on Antergos / Arch

Tags: ati, hdmi, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I've been having trouble setting up switchable graphics on my laptop (HP ENVY 14). It has an ATI / Intel combo and I'm running Antergos (with Gnome 3 if that matters). I've read on the Arch Wiki that vga-switcheroo should do the trick but I can't find it anywhere (it isn't on the official repository or AUR).

Antergos has defaulted to the Intel card which is fine except that my HDMI port is dedicated to the ATI card. I'd only really want to switch to use the HDMI port.

Comment: In the AUR: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/systemd-vgaswitcheroo-units/

Comment: Thanks. The description says that it is for disabling the discrete card. Do you have any experience using it for activating the discrete card?

Comment: It is a systemd service: you can start and stop it, which is presumably the action of switching that you are after. I have no experience with hybrid graphics, but it seems simple enough to install this package and see how it works...

Comment: Yeah. I'd already done that. It isn't switching anything.